# Set text color of QTableWidgetItem (Qt)

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

[QTableWidgetItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html) has a method for setting the backgroundColor of a cell in the table, but no method for setting the text color of that cell.

How do I change the text color of an arbitrary cell in a `QTableWidget`?

Changing the color of text in **all** cells is as simple as using this stylesheet.

```
QTableWidget::item {
    color: red;
}
```

But because the API is on the QTableWidget level (rather than QTableWidgetItem level), I find it impossible to target individual cells.

Comment: use `QItemDelegate` and change the cell color by the model index

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The method is called `setForeground()` (not sure how I missed it). Not sure how to do it in CSS only though.

Code:

```
item = QTableWidgetItem('text')
item.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(0, 255, 0)))
```

Comment: Did you finally found a way to do it using style sheet (qss)? I want to style an item/row  according to its content.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while, but you could try:

```
QTableWidget::item:selected { color:red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

class Spreadsheet : public QTableWidget

{
Q_OBJECT

```
public://

Spreadsheet(const QString &fileName = QString(),
            QWidget *parent = 0);
QString currentLocation() const;
QString currentFormula() const;

void clear();
QTableWidgetSelectionRange selectedRange() const;
bool load(const QString &fileName = QString());
bool save(const QString &fileName = QString());
void printHtml(const QString &html);


public slots:// 

void selectCellFont();
void selectFontColour();
```

// etc